# How do i loop the index results? using php?

Tags: php, json

i got this php code which take's a playlist from youtube's api and displays the video's, problem is that i can only show 25 videos per request how do i make my php script have a "load more" link which will request another 25 videos, either it can reload the page or append the additional results within the same page, i just need to be pointed in the right direction

My code:

```
<?php
    $id = urlencode($_GET['id']);
    $url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$id?alt=jsonc&v=2&start-index=1
&max-results=25";
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
    $json = json_decode($content, true);
    echo "<div id=\"info\"><center><h1><b>{$json['data']['title']}</center></b></h1><br>{$json['data']['description']} there are {$json['data']['totalItems']} uploaded in this playlist.</center><p></div><div class=\"decoration\"></div>";
    echo "<div id=\"center\">";
    echo "<ul>";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($json['data']['items'] as $items) {
        ++$count;
        echo "<li style=\"width: 300px;min-height: auto;border: none;display: inline-block;margin: 5px;padding:10px;background-color: rgba(17,0,52,0.14);border-radius: 5px;\"><a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><font size=\"5\" style=\"font-weight:bold;\">{$items['video']['title']}</font></a><Br \>";
        echo "<a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><img style=\"width:300;height:auto;\" src=\"{$items['video']['thumbnail']['hqDefault']}\" title=\"{$items['video']['title']}\" id=\"ytThumb\"></img></a></li>";
    }
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";
?>
```

i basically want the start-index parameters to loop 1,2,3 etc...
Youtube API: https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_api_query_parameters

Thanks!

Comment: So have you tried anything on your own to implement such a solution?

Comment: @MikeBrant i'm fairly new to programming in php and i read a few things but its just not making sense to me, i don't know where to begin from

Comment: First you must ask yourself. Do you want to do it without reloading the page or is reloading the page OK.  This is a key decision and will determine what technology you need to use (javascript/AJAX for no page laod or PHP if you want page load).  The youtube URL pretty clearly has parameters you can change to vary the max number of results and the result number to start at.  You just need to change up that URL.

Comment: @mikebrant I'd like it if it didn't reload the page but as I said I'm fairly new to this type of programming, so if that'll be really complicated to do then I'd go for what ever is simpler, what do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tube would only allow `max 50` result per request using `max-results` so if you run

```
$id = "UUpsSadsgX_Qk9i6i_bJoUwQ"; // for testing
$url = "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$id?alt=jsonc&v=2&max-results=50";
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$json = json_decode($content, true);

echo "<div id=\"info\"><center><h1><b>{$json['data']['title']}</center></b></h1><br>{$json['data']['description']} there are {$json['data']['totalItems']} uploaded in this playlist.</center><p></div><div class=\"decoration\"></div>";
echo "<div id=\"center\">";
echo "<ul>";
$count = 0;
foreach ( $json['data']['items'] as $items ) {
    ++ $count;
    echo "<li style=\"width: 300px;min-height: auto;border: none;display: inline-block;margin: 5px;padding:10px;background-color: rgba(17,0,52,0.14);border-radius: 5px;\"><a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><font size=\"5\" style=\"font-weight:bold;\">{$items['video']['title']}</font></a><Br \>";
    echo "<a href=\"video.php?plid={$json['data']['id']}&vidid={$items['video']['id']}\"><img style=\"width:300;height:auto;\" src=\"{$items['video']['thumbnail']['hqDefault']}\" title=\"{$items['video']['title']}\" id=\"ytThumb\"></img></a></li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
echo "</div>";


// you would get 50 results
```

To get More results you need to use [Paging through results](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Paging_through_Results)  using a combination of `start-index` and `max-results`

Try

```
https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/$id?alt=jsonc&v=2&start-index=51&max-results=50;
```

Comment: i see how the start-index and max-results work (although) i did not know the max-results go upto 50 i thought it was 25, but how do i echo a link which will loop through page 1, page 2, page 3, etc which will show results for index=1, index=2, index=3, etc